# Scroll to specific item on ItemControls on WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to search an item in an ItemsControl and scroll to the specific item that I'm looking for.

This is my XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="MessagesItemsCtrl" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding NewChatter}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MessagesDataTemplate}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="MessagesItemsCtrl_Drop"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="myscroll" ScrollChanged="MessagesItemsCtrl_ScrollChanged">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.Template>
                        </ItemsControl>
```

Does anyone have suggestions for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the `ScrollViewer` to the `ItemsControl`. Simply use the `ListBox` instead.

You can search for an item by iterating over the source collection (`NewChatter` in your case).

To scroll the selected item into the view:

1. Add a binding to `SelectedItem`.
2. Set the source property of this binding to update the `ListBox.SelectedItem` (a `Binding` set on this property binds `TwoWay` by default).
   This will trigger the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ListBox`.
3. Call `ListBox.ScrollIntoView()` to scroll any item into the view.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewChatter}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNewChatterItem}"
         OnSelectedItemChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var listBox = sender as ListBox;
  listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
}
```